Can I rename my github username to all lowercase if I am part of an organization?
I joined github with little knowledge about it and I did not realize that they recommend using all lowercase letters in username. I have capital letters in my username and I would like to change it to all lowercase. However, I am part of an organization, and I have clones, commits, pushes and pulls in multiple repos. I am afraid that changing my username will mess up something, in the worst case something goes wrong in organizations repos. On my account's personal side I only have private repos so I guess those are not affected?
I read these but there are no mentions of being part of an organization so I'm not sure how changing my username affects the organization:
Changing your GitHub username
How to change the case of my github's username without changing any letter?
Does someone know if I can change my username to lowercase without messing something up? Also, should I update remotes or do something else if I change my username?

Changing your username shouldn't hurt anything. The important thing is that the email address you're committing with is linked to your account.

My username has uppercase letters. It works fine. Where do they recommend lowercase?
